# Is there a name for "4-koma style" anime?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for animes (that are like *Nichijou*, *Pop Team Epic*) that have several parts in only one episode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there is none.

The closest genre that can fit would be Slice of Life but that's a really big genre to something specific you are looking for.

Maybe [this list](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Yonkoma) might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion, but I feel that when animated, the 4-koma best maps to sitcom. Basicaly, each sketch is a comedic situation. This translates almost exactly to how sitcoms work, by having different (and often disconnected) situations with same characters.

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience, Western sitcoms tend to be *episodic*, but with some kind of structured narrative throughout each episode--or multiple, but interwoven. It's hardly "situational" comedy without establishing and leveraging a situation!